# Finding width of div hidden by CSS

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a div tooltip that I would like to centre over SVG circles created using D3. My mouseover event triggers the div's 'hidden' class to false.

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/CjoL2IlaLWgbG0FozD3o?p=info)

Because the div is hidden, I am unable to calculate it's width and am therefore unable to centre the div on the circle the way I would like:

```
var width = document.getElementById("tooltip").offsetWidth;

...

.style("left", xPosition - (width/2) + "px" )
```

Is there a way I can get around this?

Its probably worth noting that I don't want the div to have a fixed width.

```
var w = 300, h = 500;

var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg').attr('width', w).attr('height', h)

svg.append('circle').attr('r', 20)
  .attr('cx', 200)
  .attr('cy', 300)
  .on("mouseover", function(d) {
    var xPosition = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr("cx"));
    var yPosition = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr("cy"));
    var width = document.getElementById("tooltip").offsetWidth;

    d3.select("#tooltip")
      .style("left", xPosition - (width/2) + "px" )
      .style("top", yPosition + "px")
      .select("#value")
      .text(d);

    d3.select("#tooltip").classed("hidden", false);
  })

  .on("mouseout", function() {
    d3.select("#tooltip").classed("hidden", true);
  })
```

Comment: Well, it has `display:none` by default, so therefore it does not have a width. You may have to think of some other way to hide the div, say positioning it off screen.

Comment: `pos:rel;left:-50%` doesn't work? i would avoid using JS...

Comment: Why not first make it visible, and then placing it? I don't think a user would notice the jump

Answer (score 3):

You have to first give the `div` a display value other than "none". Then you get its width. **Then** you can position it.

If you don't want the user to see the div jump, give it the style visibility: hidden while you're positioning it:

CSS:

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

JS:

```
d3.select("#tooltip").style("display", "block");
// your div is still invisible, but now has a width.
// get its width and position it now
d3.select("#tooltip").classed("hidden", false); // now it will appear
```

If you hide it again, don't forget to reset the `display` style as well!

Comment: Thanks a lot. You're answer is very clear but I still can't seem to crack this. The first time I hover returns a different width to consecutive hovers and none are centering: https://plnkr.co/edit/CjoL2IlaLWgbG0FozD3o?p=info